# How can I switch all product images on a list by a button in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am looking to create a switch on Magento that allows people to choose view products either by 'On the Model' or 'Product Only' on a the product list page.

I’ve been able to do this with a hover over a single product, but I'd like be able to alternate all product images in one go. Similar functionality to the grid /list switch, but this would change all images in the list from Small Image to Thumbnail.

Net a Porter have a switch/button that does this (http://www.net-a-porter.com/Shop/Clothing).

I've searched for extensions that have this functionality, and I've looked through posts about this topic but I was unsuccessful with both.

Answer (score 0):

If your rollover is working I think you are most of the way there because you are loading both product images into the category page.

Typically you would give the images 'on the model' their own class eg class='myshop-on-model' and the 'off the model' images their own different class eg class='myshop-off-model'.

Then you can use the DOM to select all the images of one class and set the style to, eg opacity=0 and select all the other images by class and make the opacity=1.

Are you familiar with this kind of JavaScript coding? Magento will probably have loaded prototype.js so you could use

```
$$(".myshop-on-model") //returns an array of DOM elements
```

I never use prototype.js, but your code might go something like this

```
$$(".myshop-on-model").each(function(element){
      element.setStyle({opacity:1});
});
$$(".myshop-off-model").each(function(element){
      element.setStyle({opacity:0});
});
```

and vice-versa to switch back.

(Other JavaScript libraries and other style modifications to achieve the same effect are available.)

Comment: Thank you for your message! My Java knowledge unfortunately only extends to plugging in external code rather than writing my own. I will give it a go and see if i can get it work. Thanks again!!